# Using VisualBasic to make Excel Loop Through Cells

Tags: vb.net, string, excel, vba

I am attempting to write a VB code that asks a user for input that will attach the users input to the bottom on a list. For example:

Person1

Person2

Person3

I want the input to be "Person4" and so on, and attach that input to the bottom of the list.

The code I am writing says that if the cell in range (A1:A10000) is empty, then ask the user for input and then add that input to the cell. If the cell is not empty it will cycle through to find the next empty cell. Basically, if the cell does not already have a persons name in it, it adds it to the bottom of the list.

I am attempting to write the code as:

For cell in range(A1:A10000):

```
 if cell ISEMPTY():
      InputBox("Enter Person here")
 else:
      End
```

I have no VB coding experience, so I imagine I am missing something big here

Comment: `have no VB coding experience` experience not necessary when there's google^^

Comment: Are you trying to fill all 10000 rows with names, or just the first empty row?

Answer (score 0):

Please consider using the following code:

```
Sub cyclepersons()
    Dim rngTarget As Range, cell As Range
    Set rngTarget = Application.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A10000")
    For Each cell In rngTarget
        If IsEmpty(cell) Then
            cell.Value2 = InputBox("Enter Person here")
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

You seem to be using some other type of scripting language format. As findwindow indicated Google is an easy resource to research basic VBA. Regards

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

```
Sub test()
    inputtext = InputBox("Enter any Text")
    If inputtext <> "" Then
        Range("A" & Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row + 1).Value = inputtext
    End If
End Sub
```